# R - add same element to vector without use for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm pretty new in R, I only know its foundamental concepts.

I have the `v` vector:

```
   v<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

and I would like to append to `v` four `NA` values, obtaining:

```
v(1,2,3,4,NA,NA,NA,NA)
```

T o solve this I can use a `for` loop:

```
for(i in 1:4){
   v<-append(v, NA)
}
```

My question is: are there clever and/or faster R solutions I could use?

Comment: v <- c(v, rep(NA, 4))

Comment: @joel.wilson Faster than light! Thanks. Please, edit it as answer.

Comment: Also `length(v)<-length(v)+4`.

Comment: @nicola Thank you for this alternative!

Comment: Another option is `'length<-'(v, 8)`

Comment: @akrun Thanks for this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the above comments we had found some useful answers where every new OP can view in aswer window rather than comment sections, thanks OP for your valuable answers

```
v <- c(v, rep(NA, 4)) # joel.wilson

length(v)<-length(v)+4 # Nicola

'length<-'(v, 8) # akrun
```

Please note:

in general the Joel.Wilson's option is the good one 'cause can be used to append several times a specific value (numeric, character, boolean, etc.), while other two solutions only NA values as they play on the length property.